# Axios strange behavior on get

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

I am facing a strange behavior from Axios, maybe, no for sure it is my wrong but I can when I did wrong.

here is an example of my sh*t xD

#### backend files

`Router.js`

```js
{...}
router.get("/userbooks/:uid", getUserBooks)
router.get("/userbooks/:uid/:bid", getUserBookSummary)
router.get("/userbooks/book/:bid", getUserBookDetails)
```

`Controllers.js`

```js
{...}
exports.getUserbooks = async (req, res, next) =>{
 console.log("get all books request")
}

exports.getUserBookSummary = async (req, res, next) =>{
  console.log("get 1 book summary")
}

exports.getUserBookDetails = async (req, res, next) =>{
  console.log("get the book details of the summary book's id")
}
```

#### frontend files

`Page1.js`

```js
{...}
//inside the useEffect
axios
  .get(`/api/v1/userbooks/${uid}`, config)
  .then((res)=>setBooks(res.data.data))
  .then(()=>{
    const bookIdRequestArray = {...}
    axios
     .all(bookIdRequestArray)
     .then(
       axios.spread((..response)=>setBooksRows(formatBooksData(response)))
       .catch(e => setError(e))
   })
   .catch(e => setError(e))
{...}
```

This part of the code works fine, sure it can be refactored but it works fine

```
first `.get` receive an Array of id `["01", "02", "03"]
then the array is transformed the get an Array of Promises,
and Axios does the magic part to get all book's IDs Summary
```

so in my terminal, I will get

```
get all books request
get 1 book summary
get 1 book summary
get 1 book summary
```

### My problem comes on page 2

`Page2.js`

```js
{...}
//inside the useEffect
axios
 .get(`/api/userbooks/book/${bid}`,config)
 .then(res=>console.log(res))
 .catch(e=>console.log(e))
```

in my terminal I should get:

```
get the book details of the summary book's id
```

but instead, I am receiving:

```
get 1 book summary
```

Do you have any idea what's wrong with *backend files*?

Regards guys,

Comment: `book` matches `:uid`, so this route is taken.

Answer (score -1):

as @some-user said

`book` matches `:uid`, so this route is taken.